# I am working with Matrix multiplication but have problem

Tags: python, arrays, matrix-multiplication

> index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

its working perfectly with sq matrix multiplication but having problem with
rectangular matrix 
kindly find me the mistake

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
   [7 ,8,9]]) 
B=np.array([[1],[1],[1]])
r1,c1=A.shape
r2,c2=B.shape
C=np.array([[0 for j in range(c2)] for i in range(r1)])
if c1==r2:
    for k in range(r1):
        for i in range(c2+1):
            for j in range(c1):
                C[i][j]+=A[k][j]*B[j][i]
    print("Matrix After Multiplication \n\n",C)
else:
    print('Multiplication is not possible')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
for i in range(c2+1):
```

runs out of the range, since

```
r2,c2=B.shape
```

so (c2+1) is too large.

But

```
A=np.array([[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
   [7 ,8,9]]) 
B=np.array([[1],[1],[1]])

C = A@B
C
```

or

```
C = np.dot(A,B)
C
```

is MUCH more efficient

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a reason why you are not using the built-in `np.dot()` function, but if you need to explicitly make a for loop to do your matrix multiplication, you can replace your conditional statement with the following:

```
if c1==r2:
    for col in range(c2):
        for row in range(r1):
            for i in range(r1):
                C[row][col] += A[row][i]*B[i][col]
    print("Matrix After Multiplication \n\n",C)
else:
    print('Multiplication is not possible')
```

Your resulting matrix will be of size r1 by c2.

However, if you are able to use `np.dot()`, I would recommend you follow pyano's suggestion.

```
C = np.dot(A, B)
```

Either way will yield

```
C = [[22]
     [15]
     [24]]
```